# iterating through and reading json data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I'm using ajax to get a json string from the server then using eval to turn it into an object. when I iterate through thejson data I only get the key. How do I get the value of the key. This is what I have:

```
var jsonobj = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

for (i in jsonobj){
     alert(i);
}
```

Which alerts the keys. How  do I get the value of the keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Sub-script notation: `jsonobj[i]`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var jsonobj = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');
var value;

for (i in jsonobj){
     value = jsonobj[i];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the server returns JSON you don't need to use eval. Simply specify the `dataType` and jQuery will automatically parse the result for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/script',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        for (var key in result) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                alert('key: ' + key + ', value: ' + result[key]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var jsonobj = eval('(' + xmlhttp.responseText + ')');

for (i in jsonobj){
    alert(jsonobj[i]);
}
```